# Rails Clone records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clone

How do i and is it possible clone records and it's associated records?

Example.

Category
**_*|* Product

*_*__**| Product variant

So, when i click a button, the category, products and product variants is cloned/copied.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must overwrite #clone so that all associations are also cloned, like

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products

  alias_method :original_clone, clone

  def clone
    category = self.original_clone
    category.products = self.products.clone
  end
end
```

... remember to do the same on Product and ProductVariant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start from using "clone" method. Your problem, if I have understood it right, is that you want a recursive clone. Frankly, i don't know if it exists a general solution but I think you could clone you father/sons chain by hand. Maybe it isn't an elegant solution but it should work.